# Change the URL using javascript only while not redirecting the webpage?

Tags: javascript, url-rewriting

I am working on a free domain service provider and it appends its own brand name to my URL on the browser address bar.  I want to prevent that by re-writing the URL to give the user a better look and feel.  How do I do that using only Javascript (no add-on libraries)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Modify the URL without reloading the page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page)

Answer (score 1):

```
window.history.pushState(null,'title','/something');
```

First argument is data, you don't need that.

Second one is the new page title.

Third one is the url. However you cannot completely change it, it will still be relative to the domain.

Comment: thank you. i was just wondering if there is any de limiter in javascript. like \n is for new line so is there for 'backspace'